# check if element(div) is overlap another element(div) js

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, overlapping

I build page like [https://thousandetherhomepage.com](https://thousandetherhomepage.com/)

, and I have draggable div in my page like this site.

**code**

this is my code, I develop the page and I get values from laravel in the backend and show it in views. it works fine.

```
    <div class="body" id="body">
         
                @foreach($datas as $data)
                <a href="{{ $data->sitelink }}" title="{{ $data->linkalt }}" target="_blank">
                    <img src="{{ $data->imageurl }}" alt="{{ $data->linkalt }}"  class="" style="left: {{$data->x1}}px; top: {{$data->y1}}px; width: {{$data->width}}px; height: {{$data->height}}px;">
                </a>
    
                @endforeach
                    <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    
                    </div>
        </div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
            containment: ".body",
            grid:10
        });
        $('#resizable').draggable({
            containment: ".body",
            grid:[10,10]
        });
    });

</script>
```

I want to show error(alert) when my draggable box (**#resizable**) overlapping other elements. and the draggable box to be red when overlapped.
how can I do this with jquery?

Comment: Show your attempt please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask